# Java Spark Job get file and not only contents file from hadoop

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have to read a zipped file from hadoop directory with java spark but it brings me back file with special characters calculated by spark

How can I read a zipped file in hadoop with java spark please?
below my code:

```
if(!isFileExist(sparkSession, path)) {
            final String message = String.format("HdfsReader : readFile : error : Path does not exist, path=%s", path);
            log.error(message);
            throw new ApplicationConfigException(message);
        }

        return sparkSession
                .read()
                .textFile(path).javaRDD();
```